# How to parse a tuple of "x=y" strings into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have a tuple of strings that I would like to convert into a dictionary by splitting each element using a separator. Is this possible with dictionary comprehension?

```
>>> x = ('var1=abc', 'var2=xyz', 'var3=10')
>>> y = {k: v for (k, v) in ???}  # this is where I need your help
>>> print y
{ "var1": "abc", "var2": "xyz", "var3": "10" }
```

This is as much an learning exercise as anything - so please don't answer with an alternative way of doing it (I have plenty of those) - I want to know if it's possible with a dictionary comprehension.

**[UPDATE]**

There is a slight modification that I didn't write down first - I need to strip an extraneous linefeed character from the end of each value.

```
>>> x = ('var1=abc\n', 'var2=xyz\n', 'var3=10')
>>> d = {k: v.strip('\n') for (k, v) in [e.split('=') for e in x]}
>>> d
{'var1': 'abc', 'var3': '10', 'var2': 'xyz'}
```

(Of course, now it's not in the same order - but I can live with that. Grrr.)

Comment: First off - this is the quickest I've ever seen a question answered - I actually worked it out myself in about 2 mins, by which time I'd had three answers. Amazing stuff - well done all, but Martijn gets the points for being first.

Comment: At that rate, Martijn will *always* get the points. :)

Comment: I've upvoted all the correct answers as well :-)

Comment: It's cool, don't make me force you do anything, I am just having a laugh since @martijn is *probably* the fastest answerer (is that a word?) on SO.

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown: if you really care about the order, you could use `OrderedDict((k, v.strip()) for k,v in (e.split("=", 1) for e in x))`..

Comment: "now it's not in the same order" - `dict`s are unordered.

Comment: Yup, I know that - and @InbarRose pointed this out in his original answer. I don't really care, it was just an observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to split each string twice, but yes, it can be done:

```
{elem.split('=', 1)[0]: elem.split('=', 1)[1].strip() for elem in x}
```

Result:

```
>>> x = ('var1=abc\n', 'var2=xyz\n', 'var3=10')
>>> {elem.split('=', 1)[0]: elem.split('=', 1)[1].strip() for elem in x} 
{'var1': 'abc', 'var3': '10', 'var2': 'xyz'}
```

To avoid splitting twice, use a generator expression and the `dict()` constructor instead:

```
dict(elem.strip().split('=', 1) for elem in x)
```

since it takes a sequence of two-value tuples.

Comment: you could split once using a dict + list comprehension `{ i[0]:i[1] for i in [ p.split('=',1) for p in x ] }`  ( i'm sure there's a better way to write that too )

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: but that's a double loop. I am pretty sure calling split twice is going to beat the nested double loop any day. :-)

Comment: And using simple `dict()` beats that. :)

Comment: @JonathanVanasco your answer is the closest to the one that I've gone with - as there was a hidden detail that I didn't include - I want to do some string manipulation on the values - stripping extraneous chars. I'll update my question with my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the OP noted this was a learning exercise, not an efficiency test.

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown: The `.strip()` call is easy enough to incorporate; done so now for both examples.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor

```
dict(elem.split('=', 1) for elem in x)
```

In action:

```
>>> x = ('var1=abc', 'var2=xyz', 'var3=10')
>>> dict(elem.split('=', 1) for elem in x)
{'var1': 'abc', 'var3': '10', 'var2': 'xyz'}
```

*note:* dictionaries are unsorted, and so you will not get the *exact* result you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = ('var1=abc', 'var2=xyz', 'var3=10')
>>> dict([element.split('=') for element in x])
{'var1': 'abc', 'var3': '10', 'var2': 'xyz'}
```